# Problem with Subversion committing in NetBeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.0. While trying the Subversion "Checkout" and "Update" operations there are no problems. But when I'm trying to make a "Commit" I receive the folowwing error message:

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Commit failed (details
>   follow): Connection reset CHECKOUT request failed on
>   '/svn/myproj/!svn/bln/11'

Even if I try to commit for the first time i receive same error message:

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Commit failed (details
>   follow): Connection reset CHECKOUT request failed on
>   '/svn/myproj/!svn/bln/1'

UPD: I have OS Linux Ubuntu. On Windows everything works fine (VS 2010, AnkhSvn).

Please, can anyone give me an advice what could be the possible solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.
Max.

Comment: Try using tortoise SVN and see if you can commit from the explorer (assuming you are doing this ona windows box)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to commit you get a 'checkout' error. Sounds dodgy to me!

On Linux, try committing with the svn command line (you should have it installed already) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error.  I solved it. This may work for you also. Try it. You can check details of my error here - [Subversion Error While Commiting](http://www.kodepool.com/2013/09/24/subversion-error-while-commiting/)